# Create multiple list columns from data columns of a nested data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

The goal is to create multiple list columns from data columns of a nested data frame. The following code achieves that goal. However, the code is quite long and I wonder if there is a possibility to shorten it by using tidyverse tools (`dplyr`, `purrr` etc.). In a non-nested data frame I would use, e. g., `dplyr`'s `across()`.

```
# R version 3.6.1

library(dplyr) # 1.0.7
library(tidyr) # 1.2.0


df_distribution <- iris %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Sepal.Length = purrr::map(data, ~ dplyr::select(.x, Sepal.Length) %>% 
                                            dplyr::group_by(Sepal.Length) %>% 
                                            dplyr::summarise(n = n() ) %>% 
                                            dplyr::mutate(perc = n / sum(n) ) %>% 
                                            dplyr::select(-n) ) ) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Sepal.Width  = purrr::map(data, ~ dplyr::select(.x, Sepal.Width) %>% 
                                            dplyr::group_by(Sepal.Width) %>% 
                                            dplyr::summarise(n = n() ) %>% 
                                            dplyr::mutate(perc = n / sum(n) ) %>% 
                                            dplyr::select(-n) ) ) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Petal.Length = purrr::map(data, ~ dplyr::select(.x, Petal.Length) %>% 
                                            dplyr::group_by(Petal.Length) %>% 
                                            dplyr::summarise(n = n() ) %>% 
                                            dplyr::mutate(perc = n / sum(n) ) %>% 
                                            dplyr::select(-n) ) ) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Petal.Width  = purrr::map(data, ~ dplyr::select(.x, Petal.Width) %>% 
                                            dplyr::group_by(Petal.Width) %>% 
                                            dplyr::summarise(n = n() ) %>% 
                                            dplyr::mutate(perc = n / sum(n) ) %>% 
                                            dplyr::select(-n) ) )
```

My ultimate goal is to use the created empirical distributions to randomly draw from them. However, that step is not part of the provided code but I would appreciate any pointer to helpful ressources for that, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining `dplyr::count` with `proportions` in a double `purrr::map`, and then with `tibble::enframe` and `tidyr::unnest_wider` to get a column-list format, you can do this:

```r
split(iris[-5], iris$Species) |> 
  purrr::map(\(x) purrr::map(x, \(y) dplyr::count(x, {{y}}) |> mutate(n = proportions(n)))) |> 
  tibble::enframe(name = "Species") |> 
  tidyr::unnest_wider(value)

# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#   Species    Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width   Petal.Length  Petal.Width  
#   <chr>      <list>        <list>        <list>        <list>       
# 1 setosa     <df [15 × 2]> <df [16 × 2]> <df [9 × 2]>  <df [6 × 2]> 
# 2 versicolor <df [21 × 2]> <df [14 × 2]> <df [19 × 2]> <df [9 × 2]> 
# 3 virginica  <df [21 × 2]> <df [13 × 2]> <df [20 × 2]> <df [12 × 2]>
```

Modulo some column names differences, this provide the correct answer in the correct format:

```r
identical(df_distribution$Sepal.Length$n, sol$Sepal.Length$n)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This code looks very neat and concise. However, it does not work or my R version (3.6) - the pipe operator `|>` was introduced in a later R version. R 4.2 will be available to me soon, so I will test the code later on. For now, I tried to substitute `|>` for `%>%`, but it does not work. Is the syntax `\(x)` and `\(y)` connected to the pipe operator `|>` or to "multi-level" purrr code coding?

Comment: It is not linked, but they might have been introduced around the same time. Try to use  `function` instead of \`\\`.

Comment: I can now use R 4.2 and your previous code version using, e.g., `|>` works great. Could you publish that code version again? I will then accept your solution.

Answer (score 3):

We could make a custom function to use within `purrr::map`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

f <- function(data, col) {
  data %>%
    group_by({{ col }}) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(perc = n / sum(n)) %>%
    select(-n)
  }

df_distributionNew <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    Sepal.Length = map(data, ~ f(.x, Sepal.Length)),
    Sepal.Width = map(data, ~ f(.x, Sepal.Width)),
    Petal.Length = map(data, ~ f(.x, Petal.Length)),
    Petal.Width = map(data, ~ f(.x, Petal.Width))
    )

identical(df_distribution, df_distributionNew)
# [1] TRUE
```

There is still a repetition within `mutate`, not sure how to fix that.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. However, I need a way to avoid the `mutate()` repetitions, because in my real life application the columns to be processed need to be dynamic.