# Randomly draw values from an empirical distribution by group for multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

This question is a follow up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77155620/create-multiple-list-columns-from-data-columns-of-a-nested-data-frame/77156675).

The following code creates a tibble that includes the empirical distributions of the `iris` dataset columns `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length` and `Petal.Width` separately for the groups defined by the column `Species` (i.e., the values `setosa`, `versicolor`, and `virginica`).

```
# R 4.2
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

distributions <- split(iris[-5], iris$Species) |> 
  purrr::map(\(x) purrr::map(x, \(y) dplyr::count(x, {{y}}) |> mutate(n = proportions(n)))) |> 
  tibble::enframe(name = "Species") |> 
  tidyr::unnest_wider(value)
```

My goal is to use the tibble `distributions` as a "lookup table" to randomly draw values from these empirical distributions for the shortened `iris` dataset produced by the following code.

```
iris_new <- iris %>% 
  select(Species)
```

Thus, I would like to randomly draw from `distributions` to create new "randomized" columns `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length` and `Petal.Width` incorporating the appropriate empirical distribution with respect to the value of the column `Species`.

In a dataset without groups, I would simply use `base::sample`. How can I achieve my goal in the presence of grouped data?

Comment: Could you just do `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% sample_n(n(), replace=TRUE)`?  Or, if you don't just want to re-sample rows, but individual observations from within each variable, `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~sample(.x, n(), replace=TRUE)))`.

Comment: Your suggestion works perfectly for this exact example. However, I wonder if there is some way to "score" a new dataset that includes a column `Species` and is "technically" unrelated to the `iris` dataset, meaning that the dataset could have a different number of rows and is not generated from `iris` itself.

Comment: Do you mean different numbers of rows for each group in the grouping variable?  if so, this code should handle that that just fine.  The `n()` function that defines the number of samples taken counts the number of observations in each group - not the total number of observations.

Comment: I understand your point. My goal is a bit different: I want to "transfer" the empirical distributions of the `iris` columns by group to a completely different dataset that also has a column `Species`. For that second unrelated dataset with a different number of rows in total and by group, I would like to randomly draw from `iris`'s empirical distributions by group - that is what I mean "scoring".

Comment: Ok, so just to make sure I understand, `iris` has 50 rows for each `Species`.  You're going to have, say `dat` which has a column `Species` where, let's say, n=100 (setosa), 74 (versicolor) and 103 (virginica).  You want to sample 100, 74 and 103 values randomly from the distribution in each of the other columns in `iris`?

Comment: Exactly, that is my goal. The number of rows per group may vary from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first made a function that will make the distribution.  To me, this is a bit cleaner than putting all the code in a call to `map()` or something like that.  The function `make_dist()` makes a tibble with values and the probability with which that value occurs.

```r
library(dplyr)
make_dist <- function(x){
  x <- table(x)
  x <- x/sum(x)
  x <- tibble::tibble(vals = as.numeric(names(x)), 
                  pct = c(unname(x)))
  list(x)
}
```

Next, I'll make `iris_new` - a tibble with just `Species` where the group sizes are different from `iris`.

```r
data(iris)
iris_new <- tibble(Species = rep(c("setosa", "versicolor", 
                  "virginica"), c(100, 74, 103)))
```

Next, make the distribution of each variable by species and save as `iris_dist`.

```r
iris_dist <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  reframe(across(everything(), ~make_dist(.x)))
```

The following should work whether or not `iris_new` has other variables in it beside `Species`.  First the code counts the number of observations by `Species`, then joins in the distributions.  Next, we use the `sample()` function from `base` with the values and proportions that were in `iris_dist`.  Finally, hook the result back up with the original `iris_new` with `bind_cols()`.

```r
iris_new %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  left_join(iris_dist) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  reframe(across(-n, ~sample(.x[[1]]$vals, n, replace=TRUE, prob=.x[[1]]$pct))) %>% 
  select(-Species) %>% 
  bind_cols(iris_new, .)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(Species)`
#> # A tibble: 277 × 5
#>    Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>    <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 setosa           5           3.2          1.5         0.1
#>  2 setosa           5.1         3.4          1.6         0.3
#>  3 setosa           5.1         3.8          1.9         0.2
#>  4 setosa           4.6         3.1          1.6         0.1
#>  5 setosa           4.6         3.7          1.5         0.5
#>  6 setosa           4.8         4.1          1.6         0.2
#>  7 setosa           5.4         3            1.1         0.2
#>  8 setosa           5.7         3.1          1.3         0.2
#>  9 setosa           4.6         4.2          1.4         0.2
#> 10 setosa           4.8         3.5          1.3         0.5
#> # ℹ 267 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Awesome, I compared the old and new distributions and the results appear to be correct.